# Add JavaScript to R2HTML

Tags: r

Can I add JavaScript to R2HTML?

Adding sample `<script>` tags to the R2HTML code below

```
HTMLheaderText ="Sample Report"
HTMLfile =HTMLInitFile(outdir     = getwd()
               , filename = "sample"
               , extension  = "html"
               , Title      = "R Output"
               , CSSFile    = paste(getwd(), "/html_tables.css", sep="")
               , HTMLframe  = FALSE
               , useGrid    = FALSE
               , useLaTeX   = FALSE)

 HTML(HTMLheaderText, file = HTMLfile)
 HTML(dataSet, row.names = FALSE)
 HTMLEndFile()
```

Thanks ahead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just give it a string as usual.

```
HTML('<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>', file = HTMLfile)
```

It will be wrapped in a `<p class="character">`. If you don't want that, just append to the file manually

```
cat('<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>', file = HTMLfile, append = TRUE, sep = " ")
```